# Struts 1 to Struts2 JSP taglib conversion

Tags: java, struts2, struts, taglib, struts1

So converting an application from Struts 1 to Struts 2 which so far has been going ok...

I've done much Googling on this but I can't seem to find a definitive answer. We have JSPs that are written in JSTL and some struts taglibs which is causing the issues. So...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html-el" prefix="html" %>

<html:form action="struts2action">
```

The JSP throws errors saying the mapping 'struts2action' cannot be found although is defined in struts.xml correctly

I'm guessing that the tags-html-el is the old S1 taglibs and that I need to migrate these to the new S2 taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
```

Can anyone confirm ?

We have the usual JSTL taglibs for c, fmt which I don't believe need converting ?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: Yes and yes....

Comment: S2 and S1 have nothing in common except the S.

Comment: Thanks ! Hard to find that explicitly on any documentation !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes tags need replacing with new S2 tags...
JSTL works fine and dandy :)